# Docker - Redirecionar DNS para outro DNS

Tags: docker, dns, bind

Olá,

Estou fazendo a migração de um sistema muito antigo feito em PHP 5.2, porém ele não possui 1 arquivo para configuração de banco de dados, assim, todas as conexões com o banco e feita localmente em todos os arquivos, o que seria quase impossível para mudar manualmente.

Pensei em criar um container docker com as mesmas condições da antiga máquina, mas o DNS para a conexão com o banco será modificado após a migração.

É possível fazer um bind de 1 DNS para outro? Ex: Toda vez que uma chamada for feita para o DNS dbmobile.exemplo.com ele fazer um redirecionamento para db.exemplo.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, existem alguns parâmetros de configuração da camada de rede que tornam esse tipo de tarefa trivial. Vou tomar como base o docker run, mas tudo que disser está disponível no docker create e também no docker-compose.

`--dns` | lhe permite dizer para o container quais são os dns's que ele usará.

`--add-host` | adiciona uma linha em /etc/hosts (host:IP), acredito que esse seja a melhor alternativa para você.

Essas configurações estão disponíveis da mesma forma no docker create e docker run, e um pouquinho diferentes no docker-compose.yml.

Abaixo segue o link da documentação oficial que explica esses pontos.

[docker run reference / network-settings](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings)